# A column named "MYTEST" is generated automatically in my sql server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I have a winforms project in which I add a table from sql server database into a Datagridview. 
I don't know why a column named **"MYTEST"** is generated automatically in my sql server DB when I make changes like updating the table in the database/updating the datagridview.
I have to say that there are lots of sql queries in my project but none of them include "INSERT".

### EDIT

Here are the queries:

```
sql1 = "select CONVERT(Bit,SwActive) AS SwActive, Kod AS Kod ,Nm AS Nm,(CONVERT(char,FromDate,103)) AS FromDate, (CONVERT(char,ToDate,103)) AS ToDate " + 
       "FROM Mivza " + 
       "ORDER BY SwActive DESC";
sqlupdate= "update Mivza set SwActive='" + SwActive + "',MivzaButal='" + MivzaButal + "' " + 
           "where Kod='" + Kod + "'";

sqlsearch = "select max(isnull(SwActive,0)) as SwActive, max(Mivza.Kod) as Kod, max(Mivza.Nm) as Nm, isnull(Max(convert(char,FromDate,103)), '') as FromDate, isnull(max(convert(char,ToDate,103)),'') as ToDate, Mivza.C as C, max(DateDiff(m,0,FromDate)) as DDF, max(DateDiff(m,0,ToDate)) as DDT " + 
            "from Mivza " + 
            "left join Mivza_Prt_All on Mivza_Prt_All.Mivza = Mivza.C " + 
            "left join Prt on Prt.C = Mivza_Prt_All.Prt " + 
            "where DateBitul is null and isnull(Mivza.Nm,'') like '%h%' or isnull(Prt.Nm,'') like '%h%' " + 
            "group by Mivza.C " + 
            "ORDER BY SwActive DESC, Kod ASC";
```

Comment: these are my queries: sql1 = "select CONVERT(Bit,SwActive) AS SwActive, Kod AS Kod ,Nm AS Nm,(CONVERT(char,FromDate,103)) AS FromDate, (CONVERT(char,ToDate,103)) AS ToDate FROM Mivza ORDER BY SwActive DESC";   sqlupdate= "update Mivza set SwActive=" + SwActive + ",MivzaButal=" + MivzaButal + " where Kod=" + Kod;

Comment: I also have another query(which is more complicated): sqlsearch= select max(isnull(SwActive,0)) as SwActive,max(Mivza.Kod) as Kod,max(Mivza.Nm) as Nm, isnull(Max(convert(char,FromDate,103)),'') as FromDate,isnull(max(convert(char,ToDate,103)),'') as ToDate, Mivza.C as C, max(DateDiff(m,0,FromDate)) as DDF, max(DateDiff(m,0,ToDate)) as DDT  from Mivza  left join Mivza_Prt_All on Mivza_Prt_All.Mivza = Mivza.C  left join Prt on Prt.C = Mivza_Prt_All.Prt  where DateBitul is null  and isnull(Mivza.Nm,'') like '%h%' or isnull(Prt.Nm,'') like '%h%' group by Mivza.C ORDER BY SwActive DESC, Kod ASC";

Comment: @Sunshine Please edit the question and post the code there.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: ok, it's my first time so next time i'll know. thanks.